# Why is my DynamoDB scan so fast with only 1 provisioned read capacity unit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I made a table with 1346 items, each item being less than 4KB in size. I provisioned 1 read capacity unit, so I'd expect on average 1 item read per second. However, a simple scan of all 1346 items returns almost immediately.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you follow with a second or third scan?

Comment: Am I running into "Burst Capacity"? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting. "Whenever you're not fully using a partition's throughput, DynamoDB reserves a portion of that unused capacity for later bursts of throughput to handle usage spikes."

Comment: @ChrisWilliams same result

Comment: Hmm, what do the metrics look like from the DynamoDB console, check the read capacity metrics

Comment: I ran `aws dynamodb scan --table-name witness_library_events --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL` and got ```ConsumedCapacity:
  CapacityUnits: 55.0```

Comment: Read capacity metrics chart constant at 0.01

Comment: Hmm very odd, that would indicate it uses around 3 capacity units in total. The burst capacity is split over 300 seconds. Are you 100% sure of accounts? Can you see the metrics for DynamoDB Scan Returned Item Count?

Comment: Metrics in CloudWatch report ConsumedReadCapacityUnits as 55 for my scans... Why is it using more RCUs than I provisioned?

Provisioned read capacity units 1 (Auto Scaling Disabled)
Provisioned write capacity units 1 (Auto Scaling Disabled)

Comment: Its using the Burst Capacity of DynamoDB. I imagine if you did it a few more times you would see it get throttled. I am assuming that you're the only one using the DynamoDB table so it has no interactions. I also assume you're using On-Demand vs Provisioned?

Comment: Nope, I'm using Provisioned 1 RCU.

Comment: I should probably switch to On-Demand anyway...

Comment: Do you have autoscaling enabled at all?

Comment: Nah, I think you were right. It must have been using Burst Capacity...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely down to [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting) in which you gain your capacity over a 300 second period to use for burstable actions (such as scanning an entire table).

This would mean if you used all of these credits other interactions would suffer as they not have enough capacity available to them.

You can see the amount of consumed WCU/RCU via either CloudWatch metrics or within the DynamoDB interface itself (via the Metrics tab).

Answer (score 2):

You don't give a size for your entries except to say "each item being less than 4KB".  How much less?

1 RCU will support 2 eventually consistent reads per second of items up to 4KB.

To put that another way, with 1 RCU and eventually consistent reads, you can read 8KB of data per second.

If you records are 4KB, then you get 2 records/sec
1KB, 8/sec
512B, 16/sec
256B, 32/sec

So the "burst" capability already mentioned allowed you to use 55 RCU.
But the small size of your records allowed that 55 RCU to return the data "almost immediately"

Comment: Don't you mean 512 and 256 bytes, for the increased rate?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things working in your favor here - one is that a `Scan` operation takes significantly fewer RCUs than you thought it did for small items. The other thing is the "burst capacity". I'll try to explain both:

The [DynamoDB pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) says that "For items up to 4 KB in size, one RCU can perform two eventually consistent read requests per second.". This suggests that even if the item is 10 bytes in size, it costs half an RCU to read it with eventual consistency. However, although they don't state this anywhere, this cost is *only* true for a `GetItem` operation to retrieve a single item. In a `Scan` or `Query`, it turns out that you don't pay separately for each individual item. Instead, these operations scan data stored on disk sequentially, and you pay for the amount of data thus read. If you 1000 tiny items and the **total** size that DynamoDB had to read from disk was 80KB, you will pay 80KB/4KB/2, or 10 RCUs, *not* 500 RCUs.

This explains why you read 1346 items, and measured only 55 RCUs, not 1346/2 = 673.

The second thing working in your favor is that DynamoDB has the "burst capacity" capability, [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting):

> DynamoDB currently retains up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity. During an occasional burst of read or write activity, these extra capacity units can be consumed quickly—even faster than the per-second provisioned throughput capacity that you've defined for your table.

So if your database existed for 5 minutes prior to your request, DynamoDB saved 300 RCUs for you, which you can use up very quickly. Since 300 RCUs is much more than you needed for your scan (55), your scan happened very quickly, without throttling.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a query, the RCU count applies to the quantity of data read **without** considering the number of items read. So if your items are small, say a few bytes each, they can easily be queried inside a single 4KB RCU.

This is especially useful when reading many items from DynamoDB as well. It's not immediately obvious that querying many small items is far cheaper and more efficient than BatchGetting them.